# Unicode characters in app doesn't show correctly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, unicode, fonts

How to convert string like that for example `"Bohinjska Češnjica"`. The string that I get from the website and it is not encoded in `unicode`. It works just fine in program that uses swing(`Netbeans`), but when I past the link to jar to windows console(to run `jframe` application) it doesn't show correct characters in the string `"Bohinjska Češnjica"` for characters `'Č'` and `'š'`.

```
String example="Bohinjska Češnjica";
```

**I get that string from website**.
How do I encode or show as it is `("Bohinjska Češnjica")` in a Swing application, so when i will run a `jframe` application it will show me this characters(and others unicode characters ofcourse ('Ž','ž','č' and 'Š'))?

Link 1 :[jar file of my program runned from console](http://shrani.si/f/1b/cl/45zCqM23/netbeanfromconsole.jpg)
Link 2:[when i run program from netbeans](http://shrani.si/f/m/by/28TZlx3l/netbeans.png)

*READING CONTENT FROM WEBSITE* :

```
             URL nov = new URL("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/vreme_avt.html");
            URLConnection conn = nov.openConnection(); //connect to a   website
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder niz = new StringBuilder(); 
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String vrstica = inputLine.trim(); //reading html...
```

}

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the String you receive from the website?

Comment: It's a plain text. I will post link to a images soon, so you will see what i meant.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: "plain text" has an encoding. You need to know that encoding to correctly interpret it.

Comment: I posted a code that give me html from website, then I extract informations that i need with regex...

Comment: *"I posted a code.."* That uncompilable code snippet is not an MCVE.  Please read the document again!

Comment: Problem "Unicode characters in app doesn't show correctly" is solved.

Comment: Who deside what is offtopic and what is not you ??  Your are not here to help, but just to get the points.... poor human...all off you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 8):

At run-time, we can use [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-) to determine which of the installed fonts can display a given text.  Logical fonts such as `Font.SANS_SERIF` and `Font.SERIF` typically are made of of other fonts and can cover vast ranges of different scripts.

Here is an example using the given text, with the results seen on this machine.

[image]

BTW - Google translate is telling me that is Slovenian rather than Croation, but fortunately, the exact same technique will work for any script.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CroationTextInGUI {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private String text = "Bohinjska Češnjica";

    CroationTextInGUI() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        String[] fontFamilies = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
                getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        Vector<String> croatFreindlyFonts = new Vector<String>();
        for (String name : fontFamilies) {
            Font font = new Font(name, Font.PLAIN, 20);
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(text)<0) {
                croatFreindlyFonts.add(name);
            }
        }
        final JList list = new JList(croatFreindlyFonts);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(20);
        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        final JTextArea output = new JTextArea(text, 2, 12);
        output.setLineWrap(true);
        output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(output));

        ListSelectionListener showFontListener = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                Font f = new Font(
                        list.getSelectedValue().toString(), Font.PLAIN, 50);
                output.setFont(f);
            }
        };
        list.addListSelectionListener(showFontListener);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                CroationTextInGUI o = new CroationTextInGUI();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Croation Text in GUI");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was updated. When i come home i will post a link to a pictures (how it's shown in netbeans and in windows console(when i put a link to jar file and executed))

Comment: (1+), I like that `canDisplayUpTo(...)` method. Definitely simplifies the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fonts which support unicode characters like Arial Unicode MS.